# in-app purchase Object {message: "Billing is not initialized", code: -3, errorCode: -3}

Tags: in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins, in-app-billing

I am working on ionic meteor using the in-app purchase plugin "cordova-plugin-inapppurchase" (https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase).

When I request 'inAppPurchase.buy(productId)' , I get an error "Object {message: "Billing is not initialized", code: -3, errorCode: -3}"

My code is :

```js
inAppPurchase
  .buy('com.myapp.prod1')
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
})
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

[Ionic Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZBmF.png)
For ios, it is pretty straight forward, but for android, you need to go to Google playstore, development tool, services and api then copy the base 64 licensing key.
Create a file called manifest.json in the src directory of your ionic project then add the key inside the file in the format below.

```
{ "play_store_key": "<Base64-encoded public key from the Google Play Store>" }
```

Add the file to the www folder of the ionic project by adding the path to the angular.json file found in the root folder of the project as shown below.
[Sample of angular.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtIMs.png)

call getproducts method before buy or subscribe to initialize the store.

```
inAppPurchase
      .getProducts([
        'product.id'
      ])
      .then(function (products) {
        $log.debug(products);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        $log.error(err);
      });
```

Follow the rest of the instructions here (https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase) and It should work perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

got the same error but, I can see that it helps to do:

```
inAppPurchase
          .getProducts([
            'product.id'
          ])
          .then(function (products) {
            $log.debug(products);
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            $log.error(err);
          });
```

even through you are fetching your products from, say dbs.

Answer (score 0):

The error (Billing is not initialized) message disappeared after I called the "restore purchases" first.
I now can see the Google Play "BUY" popup screen.